# log x axis on matplotlib histogram with imshow()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I have some x data in a lognorm distribution, of which I would like to plot a histogram. I have this data for different parameters, so I would like to have those parameters as my y-axis, on my x-axis I would like to have the bins of my histogram (in log-scale with reasonable ticks like 10<sup>0</sup> to 10<sup>3</sup>) - exactly like a `ax.hist()`, only using `imshow()` to get it in a more beautiful and compact way.

```
mu, sigma = 3., 2.
img = []
for i in range(20):
    dat = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma + 1/10, 10000)
    hist = np.histogram(dat, bins = 10**(np.arange(0, 3, step = 0.1)))[0]
    img.append(hist)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qn5H.png)

but I would like to have the x-axis being log and matching the bins.
I also have data for y, but that is not so much of a problem.

Comment: You only want the xaxis scale to be logarithmic? Or the histogram bins should be logarithmic too?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.0.0.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots

Comment: Thanks, your link was exactly, what i was looking for! (I want the bins to be log, so that they will be linearly spaced in a log-scale)